# Creating a ionic Cordova project with MobileFirst CLI, fails to run windows command

Tags: windows, cordova, ionic2, ibm-mobilefirst

Unable to run ionic cordova app on windows.

Steps followed:

- **ionic cordova platform add windows**
  to add windows platform to project
- **cordova prepare**
  prepare platforms
- **cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mfp**
  Add MobileFirst SDK
- **mfpdev app register**
  Register app on mobileFirst server
- **ionic cordova build windows -- --archs=ARM**
  Build application for windows *ARM*
- **cordova run windows -- --archs=ARM**
  Run application

Getting following error.

```
Error: The package or bundle is not digitally signed or its signature is corrupted.

Press Enter to continue...:

Starting application...

Get-AppxPackageManifest : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Package'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At F:\Rahul\Projects\testApp\newWorkspace\testApp\platforms\windows\cordova\lib\WindowsStoreAppUtils.ps1:157 char:41
+     $manifest = Get-appxpackagemanifest $package
+                                         ~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-AppxPackageManifest], ParameterBindingValidationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.GetAppxPackageManifestCommand

ActivateApplication:  !
Exception calling "ActivateApplication" with "4" argument(s): "Value does not fall within the expected range."
At F:\Rahul\Projects\testApp\newWorkspace\testApp\platforms\windows\cordova\lib\WindowsStoreAppUtils.ps1:164 char:5
+$appActivator.ActivateApplication($applicationUserModelId,$null,[StoreAppRun
...
+ 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentException
```

Comment: Which version of cordova are you using?  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6204

Comment: my cordova version is 6.5.0

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj835836(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Below is the error I am getting from Windows event log.

**error 0x80080204: App manifest validation error: The document root element m:Package must be defined in the http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2010/manifest namespace.**


I have installed the certificate manually to the local computer from VS 2015.

Still getting the same error.